# Add dicts with identical keys to list without overwriting values in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following problem: In a loop over a input parameter list I make an API call for each list entry. I want to then write the results into a dict and append that dict to an output list. At the end of the loop I want to print that output list. What happens is that the last API call / the last element in the input parameter list is overwritten every time I append to the output list.

```
import requests

input_parameters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

output = []
record = {}

for input in input_parameters:
    r=requests.get("https://api.domain.com/v2/param=" + str(input))

    record['id'] = str(r.json()['data'][0]['id'])
    record['descr'] = str(r.json()['data'][0]['descr'])
    record['qty'] = str(r.json()['data'][0]['qty'])

    output.append(record)

print(output)
```

The output I get:

```
[{'id': 'D', 'descr': 'foobar', 'qty': '10'}, {'id': 'D', 'descr': 'foobar', 'qty': '10'}, {'id': 'D', 'descr': 'foobar', 'qty': '10'}, {'id': 'D', 'descr': 'foobar', 'qty': '10'}]
```

The output I would like:

```
[{'id': 'A', 'descr': 'barfoo', 'qty': '50'}, {'id': 'B', 'descr': 'bar or foo', 'qty': '80'}, {'id': 'C', 'descr': 'foo foo bar', 'qty': '25'}, {'id': 'D', 'descr': 'foobar', 'qty': '10'}]
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Change the last line in the for loop to `output.append(record.copy())`. [Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy) is an explanation

Comment: Because you keep appending **the same dict** to your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output.append(record)` does not copy `record`. So, when you then do, say, `record['id'] = str(r.json()['data'][0]['id'])`, the *original*, one and only `record` will be modified.

Since there's only one `record` object, successive calls `output.append(record)` will populate `output` with references to the same dictionary object.

You can instead create a new dictionary each time:

```
record = {
    'id': str(r.json()['data'][0]['id']),
    'descr': str(r.json()['data'][0]['descr'])
    'qty': str(r.json()['data'][0]['qty'])
}
```

Or copy the dictionary with `output.append(record.copy())`. In any case, you'll need to have a new dictionary object for each element of `input_parameters`.